# Inner Join in a tricky environment, updates Sql Fiddle, issue isolated, looking for a solution?

Tags: mysql, join

So lets say I have the following records in the table 'reference_data', assume they all belong to category 224

```
parent_id   |   prop_id  |  property  | value    |  child_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    100     |    529     |    size    |    57    |    10250
    100     |    597     |    color   |    114   |    10250
    100     |    597     |    color   |    112   |    10248
    100     |    529     |    size    |    55    |    10248
    200     |    529     |    size    |    57    |    10300
    200     |    597     |    color   |    112   |    10300
    300     |    529     |    size    |    57    |    10342
    300     |    597     |    color   |    114   |    10342
    300     |    529     |    size    |    55    |    10500
    300     |    597     |    color   |    112   |    10500
    300     |    529     |    size    |    57    |    10900
    300     |    597     |    color   |    112   |    10900


SELECT `e`.`id`, `e`.`name` , `price`.`price` 
        FROM `object_record` AS `e`
      INNER JOIN `object_categories` AS `cat`
        ON cat.id = e.id AND cat.category_id = '224' 
    INNER JOIN `object_price` AS `price`
        ON price.id = e.id 
          INNER JOIN `reference_data` AS `color`
            ON color.parent_id = e.id
              AND color.prop_id = '597'
              AND color.value IN('112')
      INNER JOIN `reference_data` AS `size`
        ON size.parent_id = e.id
          AND size.prop_id = '529'
          AND size.value IN('57')
```

**My goal is to** only return a record when the prop_id's have met the value restraint for a unique child_id, what is happening now is I get the record for parent_id = 200 & not #300 returned because the first record for the size join has a color record != 112. Does anyone have a solution?

**Desired Results:**

```
`e`.`id`         |  `e`.`name`       |  `price`       
     200         |    object two     |     40     
     300         |    object three   |     50
```

Sqlfiddle linked below, it returns #200...  In the results set when I add a simple AND color.child_id = size.child_id to the last join statement in theory it should work, but when the data is out of order, it doesn't return some desired records. The reason is the first record in the DB for #300 for size = 57 has a child_id whose color = 114, but there is a record for #300 whose size is 57 and the matching child_id has a color of 112... but it seems the order that the data is in causes the problem.

The `reference_data` table is basically and EAV index table, its schema looks like (minus the 'property' string field i added for ease of reading this question):

SQL Fiddle will return #200 w/ above information.... 
For SQL Fiddle [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61f94/1)

```
CREATE TABLE `reference_data` (
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `prop_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `property` varchar(55) NOT NULL COMMENT 'string prop name for reference',
  `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Value',
  `child_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Child Entity Or Self ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`,`prop_id`, `value`,`child_id`),
  KEY `IDX_EAV_IDX_ID` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `IDX_EAV_IDX_PROP_ID` (`prop_id`),
  KEY `IDX_EAV_IDX_VALUE` (`value`),
  KEY `IDX_IDX_CHILD_ID` (`child_id`),
  KEY `IDX_INDEX_EAV_IDX_ID` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `IDX_INDEX_EAV_IDX_PROP_ID` (`prop_id`),
  KEY `IDX_INDEX_EAV_IDX_VALUE` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='EAV Indexer Index Table';

INSERT INTO `reference_data` (`parent_id`, `prop_id`, `property`, `value`, `child_id`)
VALUES
    (100, 529, 'size', 57, 10250),
    (100, 597, 'color', 114, 10250),
    (100, 529, 'size', 55, 10248),
    (100, 597, 'color', 112, 10248),
    (200, 529, 'size', 57, 10300),
    (200, 597, 'color', 112, 10300),
    (300, 529, 'size' , 55, 10500),
    (300, 529, 'size' , 57, 10342),
    (300, 597, 'color' , 114, 10342),
    (300, 597, 'color' , 112, 10500),
    (300, 597, 'color', 112, 10900);


CREATE TABLE `object_record` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'object id',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'object string name',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='OBJECT RECORD TABLE';

INSERT INTO `object_record` ( `id`, `name` )
VALUES
    (100, 'object record one'),
    (200, 'object record two'),
    (300, 'object record three');

CREATE TABLE `object_categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'object id id',
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'category id'
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='OBJECT CATEGORIES';

INSERT INTO `object_categories` ( `id`, `category_id` )
VALUES
    (100, 224),
    (200, 224),
    (300, 224);

CREATE TABLE `object_price` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'object id id',
  `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'price... assume whole #s for testing'
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='OBJECT PRICE';

INSERT INTO `object_price` ( `id`, `price` )
VALUES
    (100, 30),
    (200, 40),
    (300, 50);
```

#### SQL Fiddle

Attached: image of a problem record that doesn't return with the AND added:
[image]

Comment: more explanation is needed. Please provide some desired output in table format

Comment: DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle would be nice.

Comment: I dont get it,doesnt your fiddle already return the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add just an additional join condition :

```
and color.child_id = size.child_id
```

The whole query :

```
SELECT * FROM `object_record` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `data` AS `color`
    ON color.parent_id = e.entity_id AND color.prop_id = '597' AND color.value IN ('112')
INNER JOIN `data` AS `size`
    ON size.parent_id = e.entity_id AND size.prop_id = '529' AND size.value IN ('57')
    AND color.child_id = size.child_id
```

Comment: When I first answered the question it was clear. Now you added so much talk, impossible to understand what so ever. Sorry.